# Extracting an element whose id starts with a certain string using BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to do some web scraping with BS4.

So far I have extracted the `<a>` using

```
urls = [item for item in soup.select('h4 a')]
```

However, I only want to have the urls where the ID starts which entry.

```
<a href="http://www.sampleurl.com/static/welcome" id="entry_1">Lamborghini </a>
```

I have tried `item.id` but it does not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: `item.get('id')`?

Comment: Yep, if condition is "ID starts **with** 'entry'" `urls = [item for item in soup.select('h4 a') if item.get("id", "")[:6] == "entry_"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `re` module together with `id`.
Here's how:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

if __name__ == "__main__":
    html = '<a href="http://www.sampleurl.com/static/welcome" id="entry_1">Lamborghini </a>'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    print(soup.find('a', id=re.compile('^entry_')))
```

output:

```
<a href="http://www.sampleurl.com/static/welcome" id="entry_1">Lamborghini </a>
```

Comment: now you have 2 problems

Comment: True, but I think it's ok for one off solutions. Also it's an official/recommended way of selecting nodes https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression